# How to document experimental or incomplete APIs like @deprecated?

Tags: documentation, terminology, api, documentation-generation, javadocs

Is there a good term that is similar but different than "deprecate" to mean that a method or API is in the code base but should not be used because its implementation is not complete or will likely change? (Yeah, I know, those methods shouldn't be public, yada yada yada. I didn't create my situation, I'm just trying to make the best of it.)

What do people suggest? Experimental, Incomplete, something else?

If I'm building javadoc documentation for this API that is still in flux, should I use the  @deprecated tag or is there a better convention? To me @deprecated implies that this API is old and a newer preferred mechanism is available. In my situation, there is no alternative, but some of the methods in the API are not finished and so should not be used. At this point I cannot make them private, but I'd like to put clear warnings in the docs.

Comment: A "Unstable" tag would also be helpfull. The meaning would be something differente. "This is supposed to work OK but we might make some changes in the future".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Appropriate term is most likely **incubator**, this is one used by Google and Apache:

- [google-web-toolkit-incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/)

  > The Official incubator of widgets and libraries for Google Web Toolkit...
- [Apache Incubator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Incubator)

  > ...the gateway for open-source projects intended to become fully fledged Apache Software Foundation projects...

If you take a closer look at the projects referred to above, you may notice that "experimental" APIs (eg in GWT) tend to have "dedicated" package names, like `com.google.gwt.gen2`. This is to avoid polluting future "finalized" API intended for permanent public consumption - because, you know,

> **"Public APIs, like diamonds, are forever. You have one chance to get it right so give it your best..."** (Joshua Bloch, [How to Design a Good API and Why it Matters](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf))

Comment: I was leaning towards "Experimental" after seeing APIs like http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.html

Answer (score 12):

I would use `@deprecated` for purely practical reasons.

Although `@deprecated` does not convey the exact meaning that you would like, it has a significant advantage: Java compiler has built-in support for it. Compiling with `-deprecation` flag lets you find all places where you override a deprecated method, helping your users find suspicious code very quickly. You can use `@deprecated` Javadoc tag to explain what is really going on to anyone who cares to read your documentation. This is where you could tell the user that the API is experimental, should be used at their own risk, and so on.

Comment: +1. Excellent point. Having a built-in support is essential for such parts of the API, and encourages the users to see the documentation to understand why are those parts marked as depreciated.

Comment: I was leaning towards something like "* @deprecated This is an experimental API and likely to change" at a minimum to get the IDE and the docs to highlight the method and then to have a brief explanation.

Comment: Just rememeber that deprecated will create a lot of warnings. This might not be as bad as it seems. Being warned of experimental features could be OK.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen anything like this in other APIs, since experimental or incomplete features have nothing to do in a public API.

Since you have no choices, just put a clearly visible warning that the part of the API is subject to change.

Comment: Well. For example we have: http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/experimental/package-summary.html

By the way, using the package was an awfull idea. Once the API is unstable you need to change the package so you will breake all dependencies. A java annotation would have been much better